# exposing a function from a directive with isolate scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive which finds the window height, the offset height of the element it is bound to and then sets the max height of that element to windowheight - offsetheight.

bound to element like so

```
<div ng-style="style()" resize>
</div>
```

defined like so

```
.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var w = angular.element($window);
            scope.getWindowDimensions = function() {
                return { 'h': w.height() };
            };

            scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                var e = angular.element(element);

                scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                scope.elementOffset = e.offset().top
                console.log(scope.windowHeight, scope.elementOffset);

                scope.style = function() {
                    return {
                        'height': (scope.windowHeight - scope.elementOffset) + "px",
                        'max-height': (scope.windowHeight - scope.elementOffset) + "px"
                    }
                }
            }, true);
            w.bind('resize', function() {
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

However when I add

```
scope: {

}
```

it stops working as I am guessing the style() function is now in the isolated scope of the directive.  How do I expose that style function so that ng-style can access it?

edit1: Now looks like this

```
.directive('resize', function ($window) {
    return {
        restrict: "AE",
            transclude: true,
        scope: true,
    template: '<div ng-style="style()"><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var w = angular.element($window);
            scope.getWindowDimensions = function() {
                return { 'h': w.height() };
            };

            scope.$watch(scope.getWindowDimensions, function(newValue, oldValue) {
                var e = angular.element(element);

                scope.windowHeight = newValue.h;
                scope.elementOffset = e.offset().top
                console.log(scope.windowHeight, scope.elementOffset);

                scope.style = function() {
                    return {
                        'height': (scope.windowHeight - scope.elementOffset) + "px",
                        'max-height': (scope.windowHeight - scope.elementOffset) + "px"
                    }
                }
            }, true);
            w.bind('resize', function() {
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Use `ngStyle` in a template associated with your `resize` directive, and use `scope: true`

Comment: If there are elements within this div that are not related to the directive will they be automatically placed within the template element?

Comment: No, you must also add `ngTransclude`  in your template and `transclude: true` in your directive definition object, in such a case.

Comment: Could you not have 'resize' as an element (<resize></resize>) and inside it have <div ng-style="style()"></div> ?

Comment: Thanks I have the template loading and transcluding but scope: true still dosnt seem to be letting the function be called.  I will edit my question to show what it is like right now

Comment: @Ir1sh Seems nothing's wrong. Can you provide a fiddle? Some advices: you can directly use the template `<div ng-style="style()" ng-transclude></div>`; and why use a function (`ng-style="style()"`) rather than a simple variable (`ng-style="style"`)?

Comment: seems like having the transclude as it was in my edit was the problem moving it to the div with ng-style in the template has all working as intended.  thanks alot, if you make an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally this is what controllers or other services are for. I would rather inject a service with that method into the directive scope or have the controller own that method and then ask for it from the scope.$parent` if need be.

From the discussion in the comments, perhaps some clarification can be added. Generally your directive should use and respond to the scope, not modify it. That's what a controller is for. A service is good for encapsulating functionality that you want to share. Having the scope modified in a directive leads to problems tracking who is changing the scope.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but then I would have to add that method to every controller the directive is used?  I am trying to modify the dom/view isn't that what directives are for? and therefore shouldnt it all be encapsulated? I am genuinely asking I am sure I am missing something for you to have posted your reply

Comment: So that's would be a case for a service that contains that method that you can inject into each controller or into the directive. Generally your directive should use and respond to the scope, not modify it. That's what a controller is for. A service is good for encapsulating functionality that you want to share. You certainly _can_ do what you've done here, but IMO, having the scope modified in a directive leads to problems tracking who is changing the scope.